# sorting excel data formulaicly

Tags: excel, sorting, array-formulas

with my organization's group policy settings forcing users to explicitly click to enable macros in office files, i'd like a workaround to using vba to achieve the same result (and without having to click anything as an added bonus).  pivot tables are also out of the question.

i have a sheet with locations as column headings (A1:E1), and events as row headings (A2:A50).  the remaining cells (B2:E50) are populated with dates representing when the next event at each location will be held.  not all locations serve each event, so "N/A"s are possible.  events may be held at the same location on the same day.

Event data:[image]

my goal is to offer a secondary view of the data showing the current and next month's upcoming events (as row entries) beneath each location (column heading).  this is (relatively) simple enough with an array formula copied over and down.

formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Master!$A$6:$A$15,SMALL(IF(Master!B$6:B$15<>"N/A",IF((Master!B$6:B$15<DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1))*(Master!B$6:B$15>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)),ROW(Master!B$6:B$15)-5)),ROWS(A$3:A3))),"")`

Output:
[image: output]

however, the events are listed as they appear in the master sheet, not chronologically as i'd prefer.  i added a date column next to each event, but this is not sortable, as the array formula keeps all the content dynamic.

desired output excerpt:

```
Tampa   
19-Jan-15   Intermediate I
24-Jan-15   Introduction
26-Jan-15   Beginner I
```

Comment: Hi. The fact that you want to keep the array formula there seems to say that you think someone will be editing the source cells and you want that to automatically propagate. Is that true? If not, then I would probably just use the array formula to generate the new sheet, sort everything, and then distribute it out to all the "consumers" of the data as "read only". But I might not be understanding the situation.

Comment: It would be relatively simple to do if you never have two events on the same date - is that the case?

Comment: ......if you never have two or more events on the same date **for the same city**, I meant

Comment: @ButtleButkus that's somewhat the case.  however, the only real consumer is the person editing the source data, a position in my organization with high turnover.  but mostly, i just want to gain an extra tool in my programming toolbox.  i did this once before with someone's d&d worksheet, though in vba.

Comment: When I ran into Excel's logical limit's, I moved to Access. It was awesome for several weeks, and then I ran into its limits. Then I dipped my toe into the deep waters of PHP/MySQL, and soon dived in. There's a limit to how complex a system you can get out of an excel formula, I think, but for me the lower limit was on how large of a formula my brain could keep track of. If you have any way of experimenting with a MySQL database, I highly recommend dipping a toe in.

Comment: i used to do php/mysql dev work 12-15 years ago, but haven't really touched it since.  believe me, i'd most rather be using sql in this case, but this has turned into an interesting exercise of "can it be done this way?".  excel has plenty of tricks up its sleeve, simply awaiting a programmer's curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Upcoming** worksheet it's easier if `January` in A1 is actually a date, the 1st of the relevant month, so in this case 1/1/2015.

You can custom format A1, if required, as "mmmm" to show just `January` or "mmmm-yy" to show `January-15`

Now use this formula in A3 to get the dates in order for the month and city in question (works whether you have duplicates or not):

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Master!B$6:B$15>=$A$1,IF(Master!B$6:B$15<=EOMONTH($A$1,0),Master!B$6:B$15)),ROWS(A$3:A3)),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down column

Note: you don't have to explicitly exclude `"N/A"` text values in the formula - these will be ignored anyway

Now in B3 copied down you can use this non-array formula if you don't ever have duplicate dates for a specific city:

`=IF(A3="","",INDEX(Master!$A$6:$A$15,MATCH(A3,Master!B$6:B$15,0)))`

If you might have duplicate dates use this "array formula" instead for the description

`=IF(A3="","",INDEX(Master!$A$6:$A$15,SMALL(IF(A3=Master!B$6:B$15,ROW(Master!$A$6:$A$15)-ROW(Master!$A$6)+1),COUNTIF(A$3:A3,A3))))`

Comment: the dates and description formulas worked perfectly for the situation i described.  what if i wanted to modify this even more, displaying all events by date in three columns (date, desc, location)?  still new here so i'm not sure of stackexchange etiquette.  will edit original question if that's permissible.

Comment: The first parameter of the INDEX function is the range from which to return the data, so in the above formulas `=INDEX(Master!$A$6:$A$15,......`, so you can change that part to another column, while leaving the rest of the formula unchanged, and you will get data from another column but the same row. If the columns you want are consecutive you can even drag the formula across, make all other references absolute, except those.

Comment: i may have worded this follow-on question wrong.  the goal was to get all data into a single list, essentially deconstructing a matrix into a two-dimensional map of form (key1,key2,value) (or location,event,date in this example), except sorted by the date/event/location in that order.  i posited a new question over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036674/display-an-excel-table-matrix-as-a-list-formulaicly)