# Display an excel table/matrix as a list using formulas

Tags: excel, list, matrix, excel-formula

This is a follow-on to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018779/sorting-excel-data-formulaicly), as i think it merits its own exploration.

My source data is organized with locations as column headings (B1:E1), and events as row headings (A2:A50). The remaining cells (B2:E50) are populated with dates representing when the next event at each location will be held. Not all locations serve each event, so "N/A"s are possible. events may be held at the same location on the same day.

In the previous answer, I learned how to display events as separate lists under each location, sorted by date.  for this exercise, I wish to consolidate all events into a single list consisting of three columns (date, event, location), sorted in that order, and do so using formula. As in the previous exercise, pivot tables are out of the question.

**Source data:**

```
   A                    B               C           D               E
1                       San Francisco   Tampa       Philadelphia    Houston
...
6   Introduction        7-Feb-15        24-Jan-15   17-Jan-15       10-Jan-15
7   Beginner I          9-Feb-15        26-Jan-15   19-Jan-15       12-Jan-15
8   Beginner II         23-Feb-15       9-Feb-15    2-Feb-15        26-Jan-15
9   Beginner III        9-Mar-15        23-Feb-15   16-Feb-15       9-Feb-15
10  Intermediate I      16-Mar-15       19-Jan-15   N/A             19-Jan-15
11  Intermediate II     12-Jan-15       2-Feb-15    N/A             2-Feb-15
12  Intermediate III    26-Jan-15       16-Feb-15   N/A             16-Feb-15
13  Advanced I          9-Feb-15        N/A         N/A             2-Mar-15
14  Advanced II         23-Feb-15       N/A         N/A             16-Mar-15
15  Advanced III        9-Mar-15        N/A         N/A             30-Mar-15
```

desired output:

```
January     
10-Jan-15   Introduction        Houston
12-Jan-15   Beginner I          Houston
12-Jan-15   Intermediate II     San Francisco
17-Jan-15   Introduction        Philadelphia
19-Jan-15   Beginner I          Philadelphia
19-Jan-15   Intermediate I      Houston
19-Jan-15   Intermediate I      Tampa
24-Jan-15   Introduction        Tampa
26-Jan-15   Beginner I          Tampa
26-Jan-15   Beginner II         Houston
26-Jan-15   Intermediate III    San Francisco
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the date list in almost the same way as before because the formula doesn't care if the source is a single column or a matrix, so with 1st of the month in cell A1 in your "summary" worksheet you can start with this array formula in A3

> =IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Master!B$2:E$50>=A$1,IF(Master!B$2:E$50< EOMONTH(A$1,0)+1,Master!B$2:E$50)),ROWS(A$3:A3)),"")

Then it's probably easier next to get the cities, so in C3

> =IF(A3="","",INDEX(Master!B$1:E$1,SMALL(IF(Master!B$2:E$50=A3,COLUMN(Master!B$2:E$50)-COLUMN(Master!B$2)+1),COUNTIF(A$3:A3,A3))))

Then in B3 for the text

> =IF(A3="","",INDEX(Master!A$2:A$50,SMALL(IF(INDEX(Master!B$2:E$50,0,MATCH(C3,Master!B$1:E$1,0))=A3,ROW(Master!A$2:A$50)-ROW(Master!A$2)+1),COUNTIFS(A$3:A3,A3,C$3:C3,C3))))

All formulas need to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down the columns as far as you need

Comment: Thanks L42, I'm typing this on an iPad on the train and some of the formatting functionality either doesn't exist or I can't find it :)

Comment: Figured, I do that as well sometimes :) No worries mate.